# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).indexOf is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am creating a copy and paste program, and when I click on the box I get an error saying: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).indexOf is not a function.

I have tried using .contains but also got the same result but it said .contains is not a function instead.

```
$("#box1").click(function() {
    if ($('#div1').indexOf('#box1')) {
        $("#box1").appendTo("#div2")
    } else if ($("#div2").indexOf("#box1")) {
        $("#box1").appendTo("#div1")
    };
});
```

When clicked the box should be removed from div1 and placed in div 2 and if the box is already in div 2 it should be removed and placed into div 1.

Comment: It is right, indexOf is not a jquery function, but a js function.

Comment: Change `$('#div1').indexOf('#box1')` to `$('#div1').find('#box1').length`. `indexOf` is not a jQuery method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$.contains()`, if you want to use the jQuery functionality. Please refer to the documention of [$.contains](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/):

> **Note**: The first argument must be a DOM element, not a jQuery object or plain JavaScript object.

with `$()` you are using a jQuery object. To [get the native DOM element](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/), access the element with the square brackets:

```
$('#div1')[0];
```

Applied to your code:

```
$("#box1").click(function() {
    if ($.contains( $("#div1")[0], $('#box1')[0] )) {
        $("#box1").appendTo("#div2")
    } else if ($.contains( $("#div2")[0], $('#box1')[0] )) {
        $("#box1").appendTo("#div1")
    };
});
```

Comment: When I use .contains I get the same error saying .contains is not a function.

Comment: Try my example. Have you used `$.contains()` correctly? Show your code please with `$.contains()`.